# jQuery Before (and other DOM manipulations) Not Executing in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, dom

I've been searching through stackoverflow, jquery, and google for the answer, thinking surely there would be a definitive answer on why I can't get a jquery call to .before() to run in Internet Explorer.  It seems to work correctly in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera.

**Original Problem**
We have a fixed breadcrumb and nav bar at the top of a document.  The rest of the document contains many paragraphs enclosed in appropriate `<p></p>` tags.  Before every opening P tag, is an A anchor in the format of `<a name='paragraphidentifier'>paragraphidentifier</a>`.  Typically the format of the pargraph identifier is citational like `(1)(b)(a)`.

Since introducing the nav bar at the top of this page, any external hyperlink to one of these anchors, causes the anchor to appear beneath the toolbar.  I found what seems like a [reasonable fix by pixelflips.com found here](http://pixelflips.com/blog/anchor-links-with-a-fixed-header) by adding span tags with a class above the anchor.

I used jQuery to accomplish adding the span tags it suggests using the below jQuery code and related CSS:

```
    if(window.location.hash){
        var myHash = window.location.hash;
        var hashName =  myHash.substring(1, myHash.length);
        $("a[name=" + hashName +"]").before("<span class='anchorfix' id='" + hashName + "'></span>");
        // I have also tried .prepend and .replaceWith
    }


    .anchorfix{
    display: block;
    height: 12px; /*same height as header*/
    margin-top: -12px; /*same height as header*/
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I have additionally tried the below jQuery code to no success either.

```
$("a").each(function(index, element) {
    var aName = $(this).attr('name');
    var aHtml = $(this).html();
    if(aName) $(this).replaceWith("<span class='anchorfix' id='" + aName + "'></span><a name='" + aHtml + "' />" + aHtml);
```

I have a demo using lipsum text on [jsfiddle found here.](http://jsfiddle.net/heplah/jp0dspxw/)  If you test in Chrome, it works.   If you test in IE, it never adds the span tag.

**UPDATE**
I have updated my code above to reflect .before() instead of .prepend().   ".before()" was what I originally tried with no success and began trying other functions.

I'm not able to post images or add another link to show a screenshot, I'll put this in as plaintext URL for now which I hope is acceptable to demonstrate the problem.  `https://www.dropbox.com/s/8jqf0l93n4tv8kf/Screenshot%202015-04-23%2006.32.18.png?dl=0`

Any guidance or pointers someone can provide on why this executes correctly in Chrome but not IE (I've tested IE8 and IE11 with no success), would be greatly appreciated.   Thank you.  -Eric

Comment: The problem is that you're adding the `span` tags after the `location.hash` has already changed.

Comment: So this would only be a problem in Internet Explorer?  Again Chrome/Firefox/etc work fine.    Also, I had tried .before() with the same results.   I will check out your fiddle shortly on an IE browser to see if your code was successful, because my similar code was not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("a[name]").each(function() { // only selects tags with a name attribute
        var aName = $(this).attr('name');
        // .prepend() adds inside the element, .before() adds outside of it
        $(this).before("<span class='anchorfix' id='" + aName + "'></span>");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mp2z7hhu/

Comment: This does not work in IE, I've included a screenshot of IE11.  If you view source, you'll notice that the span tags aren't added at all, let alone before the found a tag.  However if you add a console.log in your jQuery function, you'll see jQuery is indeed correctly finding the anchor.
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8jqf0l93n4tv8kf/Screenshot%202015-04-23%2006.32.18.png?dl=0)

Comment: The spans are added correctly in IE11 for me. It's possible that something else is wrong with your browser, or else you're not correctly describing what you want to achieve.

Comment: My goal is to get those anchors to display under the fixed div bar.   I honestly don't care how I accomplish it at this point.    As to the span tags showing up for you in your IE11, I'm not sure what is different between yours and mine.  But here is a screenshot of the source of your jsfiddle from my IE11 [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8i34b6xjpim24ls/Screenshot%202015-04-23%2010.58.44.png?dl=0).

Comment: As it turns out, IE View Source was showing me the original source.   If I use Dev Tools and inspect the DOM elements, I can see that the jQuery code is being applied.   That might be the difference of what you were seeing and what I was seeing.   However the updates to the IE code aren't fixing the nav problem, but I'll research that under a different question.   Thanks for your help @Blazemonger